# Custom Date and Time Picker in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app that needs a DatePicker that goes Mon-Fri and a time picker that goes 9am - 6pm in 30 min blocks.

While I can set the max number of days for the DatePicker to be DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), this will always included on the picker Sat and Sun. To get around this, I'm looking at implementing my own DatePickerDialog (with something similar for the TimePicker).

The issue I'm facing for is that the dialogs are hidden behind UITextField, EditText and TextBox (IIRC) and I can't seem to find a way to get to the dialog from the Control.

Context.Resources.GetIdentifier would seem logical for Android (but again, I don't know what the id would be for that), with SubViews on iOS and something similar on WinPhone.

I know for iOS I'd need to create a new UIPickerView as the UIDatePicker doesn't like to be messed with. Oh the joys!

Am I approaching this the correct way or should I create my own dialog boxes with new spinners in them that only go M-F?

Comment: Have a look at the orginal implementation and then decide. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=datepicker

Comment: Did you find a solution? Can you please post?